# WINCE 6.0 Openssl Compilation errors

Tags: compilation, openssl, windows-ce

I am very new to OpenSSL. My aim is to compile OpenSSL for WINCE 6.0 OS. After spending lot of time on Google, I found a procedure to build OpenSSL for WINCE 6.0. But my attempt to build the wcecompat libraries is unsuccessful. Below is my environment

- Host Platform : WINDOWS 7
- Visual Studio : 2008
- TargetCpu : x86

Below are the steps followed to build wcecompat:

1. Downloaded the source from "https://github.com/mauricek/wcecompat/tree/master" git.
2. Using Visual Studio Command prompt for build. Declared the env following variables:

   `set OSVERSION=WCE600`
   `set TARGETCPU=x86`
   `set PLATFORM=VC-CE`
3. Created the make files using "perl config.pl" command.
4. Executed nmake command.

The build fails with compilation errors. Below are the logs:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
args.cpp
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(235) : error C2059: syntax error : '('
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(237) : error C2059: syntax error : '('
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(239) : error C2059: syntax error : '('
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(241) : error C2059: syntax error : '('
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(243) : error C2059: syntax error : '('
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(245) : error C2059: syntax error : '('
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(247) : error C2059: syntax error : '('
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(249) : error C2059: syntax error : '('
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(251) : error C2059: syntax error : '('
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(253) : error C2059: syntax error : '('
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(255) : error C2059: syntax error : '('
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(257) : error C2059: syntax error : '('
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(258) : error C2059: syntax error : '('
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(994) : error C2556: 'const wchar_t *wcschr(const wchar_t *,wchar_t)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'wchar_t *wcschr(const wchar_t *,wchar_t)'
        include\string.h(36) : see declaration of 'wcschr'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(994) : error C2373: 'wcschr' : redefinition; different type modifiers
        include\string.h(36) : see declaration of 'wcschr'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(1026) : error C2556: 'const wchar_t *wcspbrk(const wchar_t *,const wchar_t *)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'wchar_t *wcspbrk(const wchar_t *,const wchar_t *)'
        include\string.h(46) : see declaration of 'wcspbrk'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(1026) : error C2373: 'wcspbrk' : redefinition; different type modifiers
        include\string.h(46) : see declaration of 'wcspbrk'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(1027) : error C2556: 'const wchar_t *wcsrchr(const wchar_t *,wchar_t)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'wchar_t *wcsrchr(const wchar_t *,wchar_t)'
        include\string.h(47) : see declaration of 'wcsrchr'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(1027) : error C2373: 'wcsrchr' : redefinition; different type modifiers
        include\string.h(47) : see declaration of 'wcsrchr'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(1029) : error C2556: 'const wchar_t *wcsstr(const wchar_t *,const wchar_t *)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'wchar_t *wcsstr(const wchar_t *,const wchar_t *)'
        include\string.h(49) : see declaration of 'wcsstr'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(1029) : error C2373: 'wcsstr' : redefinition; different type modifiers
        include\string.h(49) : see declaration of 'wcsstr'
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(1079) : error C2264: 'wcschr' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(1081) : error C2264: 'wcspbrk' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(1083) : error C2264: 'wcsrchr' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(1085) : error C2264: 'wcsstr' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called
include\stdio.h(62) : warning C4005: 'stdin' : macro redefinition
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(81) : see previous definition of 'stdin'
include\stdio.h(63) : warning C4005: 'stdout' : macro redefinition
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(82) : see previous definition of 'stdout'
include\stdio.h(64) : warning C4005: 'stderr' : macro redefinition
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(83) : see previous definition of 'stderr'
include\stdio.h(74) : error C2375: 'swprintf' : redefinition; different linkage
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\swprintf.inl(85) : see declaration of 'swprintf'
include\stdio.h(75) : error C2375: 'vswprintf' : redefinition; different linkage
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\swprintf.inl(97) : see declaration of 'vswprintf'
include\stdio.h(125) : error C2733: second C linkage of overloaded function '_wfdopen' not allowed
        include\stdio.h(125) : see declaration of '_wfdopen'
include\stdlib.h(48) : warning C4273: '_wputenv' : inconsistent dll linkage
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(955) : see previous definition of '_wputenv'
include\stdlib.h(90) : warning C4273: '_ultow' : inconsistent dll linkage
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(884) : see previous definition of '_ultow'
include\stdlib.h(91) : warning C4273: '_itow' : inconsistent dll linkage
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(878) : see previous definition of '_itow'
include\stdlib.h(92) : warning C4273: '_ltow' : inconsistent dll linkage
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(881) : see previous definition of '_ltow'
include\stdlib.h(95) : warning C4273: 'wcstoul' : inconsistent dll linkage
        C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(889) : see previous definition of 'wcstoul'
c:\workspace\wcecompat-master\src\ts_string.h(106) : warning C4996: 'wcscpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using wcscpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
        include\string.h(38) : see declaration of 'wcscpy'
c:\workspace\wcecompat-master\src\ts_string.h(151) : warning C4996: 'wcscat': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using wcscat_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
        include\string.h(35) : see declaration of 'wcscat'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Am I missing any configuration step? I got stuck for 2 weeks now. Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Can you post the output of "perl config.pl"? Also, do you have an SDK installed for your target device?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes i have XP machine with VS 2005 and WINCE 6.0 build environment setup. Target device is CEPC. Still i get same error which i got in VS 2008.Below is the output of "perl config.pl" when executed in VS 2005 cmd prompt:

------------------------------
windows ce version:WCE600
major:6
minor:00
Compiling for Architecture:X86
Compile: -D_WIN32_WCE=0x600 -DUNDER_CE=600 -Dx86 -D_X86_
Link:/SUBSYSTEM:windowsce,6.00 /NODEFAULTLIB:oldnames.lib coredll.lib corelibc.lib /MACHINE:X86.
--------------------------------------------------

Let me know for more details.

Comment: From wcecompat build instructions, I didnt find any dependency on WINCE 6.0 SDK or platform bulder. There he declares the OSVERSION, PLATFORM and TARGETCPU environment variables and go with perl and nmake commands. Do i need declare PATH, INCLUDE and LIB variables also?

Comment: You don't need Platform Builder installed, but you do need an SDK installed for your target device. SDKs are MSI files that are generated by Platform Builder, and you have to install one before you can do native Windows CE 6 application development.
The SDK typically installs files into C:\Program Files\Windows CE Tools\<platform name>. Do you have any directories there?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. When i declared PATH,INCLUDE and LIB env variables which point to VS SDK and WINCE 6.0 SDK, it compiled successfully.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Using Visual Studio Command prompt for build...
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\wchar.h(235) : error C2059: syntax error : '('
> ...
> ```

It looks like you are using the standard visual studio command prompt, and *not* the cross-compile command prompt.

Do you have the Windows Embedded CE 6.0 Platform Builder or Mobile SDKs installed? As I understand it, Windows CE is still popular among medical equipment manufacturers (the FDA oversees medical equipment, and they don't fancy change (much like NIST and OpenSSL FIPS Validations)).

Platform Builder is licensed but the Windows Mobile SDKs are free. I don't have a link for Platform Builder because I used to install it from my MSDN discs. Here are the links to the Windows Mobile SDKs:

- [Windows Mobile 6.5 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=20686A1D-97A8-4F80-BC6A-AE010E085A6E)
- [Windows Mobile 6.0 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=06111A3A-A651-4745-88EF-3D48091A390B)
- [Windows Mobile 5.0 SDK - PocketPC](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=83A52AF2-F524-4EC5-9155-717CBE5D25ED)
- [Windows Mobile 5.0 SDK - SmartPhone](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=DC6C00CB-738A-4B97-8910-5CD29AB5F8D9)

(I had the links cribbed away, and they may be bad now a days. The date on the text file is from 2009/2010).

The SDK should get you the cross-compile command prompts. Unfortunately, I don't recall the exact steps. I have not worked with Windows CE in 6 or 7 years.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes I have WINCE 6.0 platform builder installed and using VS command prompt for build. My target platform is CEPC. So as per my knowledge, there is no need for cross-compiler command prompt. Correct me if am wrong.